# How to copy file preserving directory path in Linux?

Tags: linux, directory, copy

I have Eclipse projects and ".project" file in them, the directory structure looks like '`myProject/.project`'. I want to copy these '.project' files to another directory, but I want the enclosing directory name to be preserved.

Let's say I have '`a/myProject/.project`', I want to copy '`myProject/.project`' to '`b`', so it be '`b/myProject/.project`', but '`b/myProject`' doesn't exist. When I try in a:

```
 cp -r ./myProject/.project ../b
```

it copies only '.project' file itself, without 'myProject' directory. Please advise.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

The switch you need is `--parents`, e.g.:

```
jim@prometheus:~$ cp --parents test/1/.moo test2/
jim@prometheus:~$ ls -la test2/
total 42
drwxr-xr-x   3 jim jim    72 2010-09-14 09:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 356 jim jim 43136 2010-09-14 09:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 jim jim    72 2010-09-14 09:32 test
jim@prometheus:~$ ls -la test2/test/1/.moo
-rw-r--r-- 1 jim jim 0 2010-09-14 09:32 test2/test/1/.moo
```

Comment: Note that the --parents flag requires -r as well, otherwise it fails.

Comment: @MosheZvi It fails only when `cp --parents <SOME DIRECTORY> <DESTINATION>` is used.

Comment: i know this is *nix but I did try on `macOS` and `--parents` option does not exist

Answer (score 40):

You can also use `rsync -R`, which works on OSX where `cp --parents` isn't available.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13855290/598940

Answer (score 10):

Use `tar` with something like:

```
mkdir b; tar cpf - myProject/ | tar xpf - -C b/
```

(Not tested. Give it a dry run first or try in a mockup scenario.)

Comment: works surprisingly well! On mac:

mkdir b;
tar -c -f new.tar $(cat myP);
tar -x -f new.tar -C b/; #myP is text file with list of paths-to-files to be copied

Answer (score 5):

First use `mkdir -p` to create the destination folder with recursive parent path creation. Then copy the contents to the destination folder:

```
mkdir -p b/myProject/.project
cp -r a/myProject/.project/file b/myProject/.project
```

Answer (score 5):

I use cpio in combination with find. [Explanation here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio#Copy).

Example for your use case:

```
find /a/myProject/.project/ -type f | cpio -p -dumv /b/.
```

This command finds all files in `/a/myProject/.project/` and copies, while preserving the path, any files contained within.

Comment: .project is a file, not dir!

Comment: This is most flexible as you can pick the files/directories to be copied, discard the -v option to avoid verbose outputs, and add the --quiet option can suppress the "xx blocks" at the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
cp -P a/myProject/.project b
```

See `man cp` for more information.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help. It only copies '.project' itself into b, but it doesn't copy 'myProject'.

Comment: `-P` is don't follow symbolic links

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to `--parents` it is also required to add `-r` option in order to avoid omitting the copy of most inner directory

```
$ cp --parents test/1/.moo test2/
cp: omitting directory ‘test/1/.moo’
```

So the command that works for me is

```
$ cp --parents -r test/1/.moo test2/
```

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that there appears to be a bug in `cp --parents`. When I used
`--parents` along with `--preserve=all`, the date and time attributes of SOME
destination directories were NOT preserved.

The following link seems to confirm that this is a bug: [bug#8767: cp: --preserve=all doesn't work for the parents when --parent is
used](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2011-09/msg00065.html).

So it looks as though you can't rely on attributes being preserved when using
`--parents` along with such as `--preserve=all` or `-p`.

Answer (score -2):

I used `--parents` with the `cp` command and worked perfeclty with me. for more details always use the manual.
Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't add anything to the other 5 answers.

Comment: Answerers please note that .project in Eclipse is a file, not directory. So e.g. mkdir -p a/.project makes no sense.